# How to show local string in StatefulWidget?

Tags: internationalization, dart, flutter, statefulwidget

I've learned How to use i18n via StatelessWidget for my flutter practice,
but still not work via StatefulWidget.

I can simply replace the following code

```
title: new Text(S.of(context).title)
```

with a const String, for example:

```
title: const Text("A Test Title");
```

So I think every thing else should be okay. The only problem is i18n not work.

**Could some body help me, "How to use i18n via StatefulWidget on flutter ?"**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'generated/i18n.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  BuildContext c;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tiles = new List<Widget>();

    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(S.of(context).title), // Here is the problem
        ),
        body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(),
            new ListView(
              children: tiles,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: [S.delegate],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      localeResolutionCallback: S.delegate.resolution(
          fallback: new Locale("en", "")
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use widget.title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `context` you're using doesn't have a `MaterialApp` as a parent. Instead, it has a `MaterialApp` as a child.

The problem is, `S` instance you're trying to fetch using `S.of(context)` is stored inside `MaterialApp`. Hence the error.

What you can instead do is use a different `context` where that `context` has `MaterialApp` in its parents.

The easiest way to achieves this is by wrapping a part of your app into a `Builder`.

Something like :

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      const title = S.of(context).title; // works now because the context used has a MaterialApp inside its parents
      return Scaffold(...);
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. This morning I tried the same way with yours, and finally works.

Comment: This solution is still available in 2020. Unfortunately most of tutorials written/video are based only on Stateless widgets which have different type of context beside Statefull Widgets

Comment: This also worked for me, Except that mine is a StatelessWidget